vs code git : githooks runner point to a no existing location
I have a project called yahya-os which has a submodule ui-common, as shown in the picture. They are on different branches. I want to stash the changes made in ui-common, but I got this error. Do you have any idea how to solve that? Note that I can stash changes normally in the yahya-os folder.
project structure : (https://i.sstatic.net/e95ffBvI.png)
message i got when i statsh in ui-common : (https://i.sstatic.net/oiMrLGA4.png)

Hi, welcome to SO. SO favors text over images. Can you please copy/paste the text of the error messages in the body of your question?
